# Unable to debug azure project in the emulator

Tags: iis, azure, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

Error:

> There was an error attaching the debugger to the IIS worker process for URL `http://127.255.0.0:82/` for role instance ...

So basically I have:

- Windows 8 Enterprise
- Visual Studio 2012
- Azure SDK 1.7

Project with two roles:

- Worker role
- Web Role (ASP.NET MVC 4)

What have I tried

- Enabled running 32-bit applications in AppPool
- Checked for `<compilation debug="true">` in Web.config
- aspnet_regiis.exe -i

Azure project is configured to run at Full IIS (with Express it's working like a charm, but need full IIS)

Comment: If the Web Role is the startup project does it load ok (granted that may be hard to test if there are Azure SDK calls) - if not (or even if so) running aspnet_regiis might not hurt.  Does this happen on a completely new Cloud Service project with a single MVC role as well?  This could isolate whether it's EVERY app or just the one you're working on.

Comment: Oh, I've done so much things that I even didn't mention everything. Yes, web role is running okay via Debug -> Start new instance.

Comment: understood (and kind of figured that might be the case) any additional clues in Event Viewer? for instance, saw one circumstance where web role was crashing before debugger could attach (like a problem in RoleEntryPoint or global.asax).  Also, if you haven't already, log a case via http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/contact/ - can't hurt to pursue multiple paths.

Comment: Actually I'm supossing that this is a IIS configuration problem rather than azure. Because at IIS Express it's working with no problem. But it's really strange that I've created new solution, added a web role, changed in azure project properties IIS to Web Version and get this error. I have really big doubts that testers in Microsoft didn't notice this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aspnet_regiis.exe -ir from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` solved the problem. I've done this from developer command promt which has 64-bit path enviroment. This is for 32-bit.