# Error attaching debugger to IIS worker process

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-roles

I have a strange problem in that my MVC Azure application is running/debugging on my desktop but not my laptop. On the laptop I get an error

> Error attaching debugger to IIS worker process

However I don't get the problem when running/debugging a simpler/smaller MVC Azure project on the laptop. The only difference between the laptop and desktop is that the laptop is running Windows 8. A prior version of the application did run on the laptop but has suddenly stopped working and I can't trace back why.

Has anyone got any ideas as to what the cause could be.

Comment: I think we'd need more info about what's changed in the project since it used to work. Also whether you've made any changes to the laptop (IIS settings, new software that could affect it, etc)

Comment: The problem is that I can't work out what has changed and I have not made any changes to the laptop. The strange thing is that a smaller test project using the same controls works on the laptop. Just not the larger project.

Comment: How are things set up in IIS for the larger project? App pool identity used, etc. Is the smaller project running through IIS as well?

Comment: Also, when running without the debugger i.e. Cntrl-F5 I don't get the error. However after launching the browser it just hangs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409083/debugging-azure-error-attaching-the-debugger-to-the-iis-worker-proccess

Comment: As far as I can see the larger and smaller projects are set up the same.

Comment: What makes one larger and the other smaller? Also, does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340641/unable-to-debug-azure-project-in-the-emulator - or this? http://lukianol.wordpress.com/2012/09/28/there-was-an-error-attaching-the-debugger-to-the-iis-worker-process/

Comment: I met this problem and 1. I restart my computer, it OK. 2. If I use IIS Express (not IIS) then it OK.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use TcpView(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) to see if there is a port conflict on the machine with the port used by IIS Express